# Create an intersection of two key's values, if keys in 2 seperate hashes are equal. Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, intersection

I am trying to create an intersection of the values of hash1 with those of hash2, if those values share the same key.  Here is my code so far.  I am able to generate two hashes --> data and data1.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pp'
require 'set'
data = {}
File.read(ARGV[0]).each do |l|
  l.chomp!
  key, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, value10, value11, value12 = l.split(/\s+/)
  data[key] ||= {}
  values = [value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, value10, value11, value12]
  data[key] = values.compact!

end

data1 = {}
File.read(ARGV[1]).each do |l|
  l.chomp!
  value = l.split(/\s+/)
  data1[value[0]] ||= {}
  data1[value[0]] = [value] 
end
```

So, my main goal is for each key in hash1, keep only those values that also are present at that identical key in hash2, otherwise remove those values from hash1.  I am not concerned with any keys present in Hash2 that are not present in Hash1, btw.

I know arrays can be intersected using "&" and "set", though I have not been able to accomplish this in my script so far.

Any advice would be great.  Thanks.

For Theo:

Yes.
hash1 { alpha: [a,b,c,d,e], bravo: [f,g,h,i,j], charlie: [k,l,m,n,o], delta:[p,r]}

hash2 { alpha: [a,c,q,z], bravo: [z,x], charlie: [k,l,m,n]}

So, the intersection would look like this.

hash3 { alpha: [a,c], bravo:[nil], charlie: [k,l,m,n]}

Comment: What should happen with keys in hash1 which don't exist in hash2?

Comment: It's not easy to decipher what it is that you want. Could you provide a simple example of how the two hashes might look, and what you want to get?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include that possibility.  In that case, those keys in hash1 should be removed.

Comment: Theo, edited my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a regular intersection of two hashes do:

```
Hash[h1.to_a & h2.to_a]
```

But your case is a little bit different. You can get the intersection you are looking for with this code:

```
hash1 = {:alpha => [:a,:b,:c,:d,:e], :bravo => [:f,:g,:h,:i,:j], :charlie => [:k,:l,:m,:n,:o], :delta => [:p,:r]}
hash2 = {:alpha => [:a,:c,:q,:z], :bravo => [:z,:x], :charlie => [:k,:l,:m,:n]}

common_keys = hash1.keys & hash2.keys 
  # => [:alpha, :bravo, :charlie]
intersection = common_keys.map { |k| [k, hash1[k] & hash2[k]] } 
  # => [[:alpha, [:a, :c]], [:bravo, []], [:charlie, [:k, :l, :m, :n]]]
intersection = intersection.reject { |k, v| v.empty? } 
  # => [[:alpha, [:a, :c]], [:charlie, [:k, :l, :m, :n]]]
Hash[intersection]
  # => {:alpha=>[:a, :c], :charlie=>[:k, :l, :m, :n]}
```

Your example includes `:bravo => [nil]`, but I think that is an error since `nil` is not a common element between the `:bravo` key in `hash1` and `hash2`, so it doesn't make sense. If you want an empty list for keys that are in `hash1` and `hash2` but have no common elements in their value lists you can remove the third line, which otherwise removes those.

Comment: Theo, yes that is correct, and thanks for your help!  The only exception is that I want {:b => [222]} .

Comment: I changed my answer to better reflect the example you added in your question.

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
data  = { a: [11], b: [22, 222], c: [33] }
data2 = { b: [222, 2222], d: [4444] }

Hash[data.map {|k, v| if data2[k] then [k, v & data2[k]] end }.compact]
# => { b: [222] }
```

Comment: Hi Jorg.  Thanks for the help. I am getting an error when I try and run your solution.  "intersection.rb:23:in `[]': odd number of arguments for Hash (ArgumentError)
 from intersection.rb:23"

Comment: I am able to use your solution now, however it think I need to keep looking at it, as it is not generating a true intersection of the values.  Thanks again!!

Comment: @user511038: Given that your question contained no sample data, no testcases, no example runs, no specification of what you want the code to do and the code you posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question (and even if it *did*, it wouldn't be of any help, since it depends on external files that you didn't post), I tried my best decipher your cryptic description. If there's anything I misinterpreted, let me know and I can fix it.

Comment: Jorg, yes, I did post what I wanted the code to do.  If I hadn't done so, how would you even make an attempt at writing your code in your answer?  Also, posting my code may not be directly relevant to the question at hand, but from what I have seen on these forums, asking a question without even attempting any leg-work yourself is a major violation of forum etiquette.  Anyway, as I said above, thank you for your help and I will keep working on it.

Comment: @user511038: Now that you have provided an actual testcase and I understand what it actually is that you are trying to do, the change was trivial. See the edited solution above.

Comment: Hi Jorg.  Your code works very well, thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash[h2.collect { |k,v| h1[k] ? [k, h1[k] & h2[k]] : [] }]
```

Additionally, you check the size of h1.keys compared to h2.keys first and then iterate over the smaller one first. It loses a bit of the clarity of the above, but it will perform a lot better for larger hashes with a disparity in sizes.

Comment: Hi Stephen.  Thanks!  I will certainly give this a try.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge_hash(hash1, hash2)
  result = {}

  hash1.keys.each do |k|
    result[k] = hash1[k] & hash2[k] unless hash2[k].nil?
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: Hi nathan.  I have not tried your code yet, but I will.  Thank you for your help